# SQL Server Agent Job running stored proc VERY slowly

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, sql-agent-job

I have a stored procedure that essentially rebuilds a pivot table.  It builds the new data in a temp table, then truncates the permanent table and inserts the new data, and finally drops the temp table.

When I execute the stored proc (or the T-SQL code directly) in Management Studio, it takes about a minute.  While I know this isn't the most efficient of processes, I'm OK with it.

My problem comes in when I try to schedule this task to run every 20 minutes or so.  When I setup a SQL Server Agent Job to execute the stored proc, its now taking almost an hour and a half... that's right, 90 TIMES SLOWER!

I found this post: [SQL Server Agent Job Running Slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084333/sql-server-agent-job-running-slow), which seems to be a similar issue, but `set nocount on` doesn't seem to have any effect whether I call it at the beginning of the stored proc or before the `exec` command in the SQL Agent Job. My query doesn't use any cursors, though I am doing a `cross apply` on a table valued function (which also doesn't use any cursors).

I'm obviously missing something, but I don't even know where to start on this.  I thought by creating the stored proc I would have avoided these types of issues.

For reference, the stored proc looks something like the following:

```
create table #temp
(
  ID    int,
  data1 float,
  data2 float
)
insert into #temp(ID, data1, data2)
select t.ID, d.data1, d.data2
from tbl1 t
  cross apply dbo.getInterestingData(t.ID, t.param1) d
where d.useMe = 1

truncate table dataPivot

insert into dataPivot(ID, data1, data2)
select ID, data1, data2
from #temp

drop table #temp
```

Comment: I just tried changing the temp table to a table variable. Running in SSMS didn't seem to change.  I stopped the SQL Server Agent task after 15 minutes.